# PK violated in oracle sql

Tags: oracle, insert, sequence, primary-key, unique-constraint

I wonder if anyone can help me with this. I ran the whole thing in sql but its gives me this error:

> Error report:
>   SQL Error: ORA-00001: unique constraint (GAMES.ATHLETE_PK) violated
>   00001. 00000 -  "unique constraint (%s.%s) violated"
>   *Cause:    An UPDATE or INSERT statement attempted to insert a duplicate key.
>              For Trusted Oracle configured in DBMS MAC mode, you may see
>              this message if a duplicate entry exists at a different level.
>   *Action:   Either remove the unique restriction or do not insert the key.

I want to insert all records at once in a single transaction. and also using sequences to generate new primary keys. I tried inserting one by one and its okay. But if i insert all at once, this is the error...

```
INSERT ALL 
    INTO athlete (athlete_no, athlete_name, athlete_birthdate, athlete_birthplace, athlete_born_country, athlete_gender, athlete_height, athlete_weight, athlete_team_country)
    VALUES (athlete_no_seq.nextval, 'Michael Phelps', to_date('1985-06-30','yyyy-mm-dd'), 'Towson', 'USA', 'M', 193, 88, 'USA')
    INTO athlete (athlete_no, athlete_name, athlete_birthdate, athlete_birthplace, athlete_born_country, athlete_gender, athlete_height, athlete_weight, athlete_team_country)
    VALUES (athlete_no_seq.nextval, 'Stephanie Rice', to_date('1988-06-17','yyyy-mm-dd'), 'Brisbane', 'AUS', 'F', 176, 67, 'AUS')
    INTO athlete (athlete_no, athlete_name, athlete_birthdate, athlete_birthplace, athlete_born_country, athlete_gender, athlete_height, athlete_weight, athlete_team_country)
    VALUES (athlete_no_seq.nextval, 'Rebecca Adlington', to_date('1989-02-17','yyyy-mm-dd'), 'Mansfield', 'GBR', 'F', 179, 870, 'GBR')
    INTO athlete (athlete_no, athlete_name, athlete_birthdate, athlete_birthplace, athlete_born_country, athlete_gender, athlete_height, athlete_weight, athlete_team_country)
    VALUES (athlete_no_seq.nextval, 'Lee Chong Wei', to_date('1982-10-21','yyyy-mm-dd'), 'Perak', 'MAS', 'M', 170, 60, 'MAS')
    INTO athlete (athlete_no, athlete_name, athlete_birthdate, athlete_birthplace, athlete_born_country, athlete_gender, athlete_height, athlete_weight, athlete_team_country)
    VALUES (athlete_no_seq.nextval, 'Lin Dan', to_date('1983-10-14','yyyy-mm-dd'), 'Fujian', 'CHN', 'M', 176, 68, 'CHN')
    INTO athlete (athlete_no, athlete_name, athlete_birthdate, athlete_birthplace, athlete_born_country, athlete_gender, athlete_height, athlete_weight, athlete_team_country)
    VALUES (athlete_no_seq.nextval, 'Peter Gade', to_date('1976-12-14','yyyy-mm-dd'), 'Aalborg', 'DEN', 'M', 183, 73, 'DEN')
INTO competes (athlete_no, discipline_code, sg_gameno)
    VALUES (athlete_no_seq.currval, (SELECT discipline_code FROM discipline where discipline_name = 'Swimming'), 30)
    INTO competes (athlete_no, discipline_code, sg_gameno)
    VALUES (athlete_no_seq.currval, (SELECT discipline_code FROM discipline where discipline_name = 'Swimming'), 30)
    INTO competes (athlete_no, discipline_code, sg_gameno)
    VALUES (athlete_no_seq.currval, (SELECT discipline_code FROM discipline where discipline_name = 'Swimming'), 30)
    INTO competes (athlete_no, discipline_code, sg_gameno)
    VALUES (athlete_no_seq.currval, (SELECT discipline_code FROM discipline where discipline_name = 'Swimming'), 30)
    INTO competes (athlete_no, discipline_code, sg_gameno)
    VALUES (athlete_no_seq.currval, (SELECT discipline_code FROM discipline where discipline_name = 'Swimming'), 30)
    INTO competes (athlete_no, discipline_code, sg_gameno)
    VALUES (athlete_no_seq.currval, (SELECT discipline_code FROM discipline where discipline_name = 'Swimming'), 30)
INTO venue(venue_no, venue_name, venue_location, venue_usedfrom, venueused_to, venue_seatingcapacity, venue_structure, venue_use)
    VALUES(venue_no_seq.nextval, 'Aquatics Centre', 'Olympics Park, East London', to_date('2012-07-28','yyyy-mm-dd'), to_date('2012-10-08','yyyy-mm-dd'), 17500, 'N', 'P')
    INTO venue(venue_no, venue_name, venue_location, venue_usedfrom, venueused_to, venue_seatingcapacity, venue_structure, venue_use)
    VALUES(venue_no_seq.nextval, 'Wembley Arena', 'North West London', to_date('2012-07-28','yyyy-,mm-dd'), to_date('2012-08-05','yyyy-mm-dd'), 6000, 'E', 'P')
SELECT * FROM dual;
commit;
```

Comment: 'You cannot specify a sequence in any part of a multitable insert statement' - see the last bullet [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_9014.htm#i2080134). All of the references to a sequence get the same value. Do you really need to insert them all in a single *statement*, rather than just in a single *transaction*?

Comment: I need to treat the insert of each element as single transaction. I dont really understand by "treating the insert of one element as single transaction".

Comment: May i know what is the right way to type out the whole statement?

Comment: Split your multitable insert into multiple distinct insert operations. Make it so that you don't have autocommit enabled on the session, and commit just once after you've done all the inserts. It is then the single commit that closes the single transactions, even though there are multiple insert statements made during the transaction.

Comment: Multiple distinct insert operation means? Is it okay if you give an example juha? :)

Comment: Or possibly use a stored procedure to insert the related records together, and call that.

Comment: "Multiple distinct insert operation means?" It means a separate INSERT statement for each VALUES clause.  It's the normal, most basic means of inserting one record at a time.

Comment: Oh alright, thank you for the explanation :) sorry i am sort of a beginner in doing these.

Answer (score 2):

The posted code uses the INSERT ALL syntax to insert multiple rows in a single statement.  It attempts to use sequence NEXTVAL to generate a unique identifier for each row.

The [documentation is quite clear](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/pseudocolumns002.htm#sthref812) on the functioning of NEXTVAL:

> "Within a single SQL statement containing a reference to NEXTVAL,
>   Oracle increments the sequence once"

So each of those calls to NEXTVAL will return the *same* value from the sequence, and so the statement hurls ORA-00001.

The problem is that the OP's code is misusing the multi-table insert syntax.  It is intended to distribute rows from one set of source data across several tables, or conditionally manipulate the rows into one table.  In either case it  assumes the source data already has a primary key.

There are various ways of working around this, from hardcoding the ID to using multiple single table insert statements.

Here is one way to populate these tables with the posted data:

```
insert into athlete (athlete_no, athlete_name, athlete_birthdate, athlete_birthplace, athlete_born_country, athlete_gender, athlete_height, athlete_weight, athlete_team_country)
select athlete_no_seq.nextval , nm, dt, pl, ctry, gn, ht, wt, tm
from (
    select 'Michael Phelps' nm, to_date('1985-06-30','yyyy-mm-dd') dt, 'Towson' pl, 'USA' ctry, 'M' gn, 193 ht, 88 wt, 'USA' tm from dual union all
    select 'Stephanie Rice', to_date('1988-06-17','yyyy-mm-dd'), 'Brisbane', 'AUS', 'F', 176, 67, 'AUS' from dual union all
    select 'Rebecca Adlington', to_date('1989-02-17','yyyy-mm-dd'), 'Mansfield', 'GBR', 'F', 179, 870, 'GBR' from dual union all
    select 'Lee Chong Wei', to_date('1982-10-21','yyyy-mm-dd'), 'Perak', 'MAS', 'M', 170, 60, 'MAS' from dual union all
    select 'Lin Dan', to_date('1983-10-14','yyyy-mm-dd'), 'Fujian', 'CHN', 'M', 176, 68, 'CHN' from dual union all
    select 'Peter Gade', to_date('1976-12-14','yyyy-mm-dd'), 'Aalborg', 'DEN', 'M', 183, 73, 'DEN' from dual
    )
/    

insert into competes (athlete_no, discipline_code, sg_gameno)
select ath.athlete_no, disc.discipline_code, 30
from athlete ath
     cross join discipline disc
where disc.discipline_name = 'Swimming'
/

insert into venue(venue_no, venue_name, venue_location, venue_usedfrom, venueused_to, venue_seatingcapacity, venue_structure, venue_use)
select venue_no_seq.nextval, nm, loc, dtf, dtt, cap, vs, vu
from (
    select 'Aquatics Centre' nm, 'Olympics Park, East London' loc, to_date('2012-07-28','yyyy-mm-dd') dtf, to_date('2012-10-08','yyyy-mm-dd') dtt, 17500 cap, 'N' vs, 'P' vu  from dual union all
    select 'Wembley Arena', 'North West London', to_date('2012-07-28','yyyy-,mm-dd'), to_date('2012-08-05','yyyy-mm-dd'), 6000, 'E', 'P'  from dual 
    )
/
```

Comment: Thank you, my friend.  Thank you.