# Oracle before insert all trigger

Tags: oracle, triggers, insert

I want to create a trigger before when insert into more rows.
Before inserting the new data, i want to delete the earlier version of those by an id.

e.g.:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER mytableTrigger
BEFORE INSERT ALL ON mytable
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM mytable WHERE column2 = fooId; --I want to get fooId in here.
END;

INSERT ALL
  INTO mytable (column1, column2, column3) VALUES (Seq.nextval(), fooId, 'val1.3')
  INTO mytable (column1, column2, column3) VALUES (Seq.nextval(), fooId, 'val2.3')
  INTO mytable (column1, column2, column3) VALUES (Seq.nextval(), fooId, 'val3.3')
SELECT * FROM dual;
```

If it would be a simple row-level trigger then I can get fooId with :new.fooId.
But it isn't.
So, can i get or give an id to INSERT ALL Trigger?

THX.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`INSERT ALL` is a special case of `INSERT`, it will fire standard `BEFORE/AFTER INSERT` triggers.

You would need `ON EACH ROW` triggers to access the values of the row you are inserting. <strike>(un)</strike>Fortunately, you can't use row triggers to query the table you are trying to modify: you will run into `ORA-04091`. See this [recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15161064/abort-insert-update-operation-in-trigger-using-pl-sql/15161423#15161423) for why you should not use triggers if you want to do this kind of logic.

Use procedures. Easier to code, easier to maintain and debug. Triggers are the `GOTO` of database logic.

Here's a similar [advice from Tom Kyte](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:9579487119866):

> anyway, you can do too much work in triggers, this may well be that time -- there is 
>   nothing wrong with doing things in a more straightforward fashion (eg: using a stored 
>   procedure to implement your transaction) [...]
>   The logic is a whole lot more understandable that way (and 
>   maintainable and testable and everything)

---

With hindsight your case is even more complicated than what I thought at the beginning. Now my understanding of your requirement is: you want your statement to first remove all rows that will have the `fooID` identifier, then insert another set of rows. However, the number of rows could be different so a standard row-per-row approach won't work.

I'm now not even sure you could do this with triggers, **even if you persisted with this approach** !

Comment: if I understand the question correctly, a merge won't work. The poster is matching on fooID, which will be the same for all of the rows in the merge set. That leads to an ORA-30926. Also, you can't use sequences along with a UNION. I think your original advice to use a procedure is still the best answer. Don't think I know all this off the top of my head - I also thought a MERGE was the answer until I tried it and ran into these various brick walls :)

Comment: The `insert all` approach would also get the same sequence value for all rows, which is another reason not to use it. This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12364886/266304) has a link to the relevant docs.

Comment: @alexpoole for some reason I thought it would get different ids, thanks for the correction :)

Comment: `merge` will get different IDs, `insert all` won't, according to that link. Can't you just move the `nextval` into the values clause, instead of generating it in the union? The merge seems to be on `fooid` matching `column2`, not `column1` which is getting the `nextval`, so you don't want it in the `on` clause... I think... Although from your latest update I think I'm oversimplifying what's happening anyway.

Comment: @alexpoole I think the problem is even more complex: the matching will be done on a non-unique column so merge can't be used !

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any reliable relational database that will allow a table to be deleted or updated at the same time as it's being inserted into from the same transcriptional statement.
Yet this is what you want to do. It's called a mutating table. 
 I know that Oracle won't let this. 
In your example when Inserting you want to insert some data, so there will be a recursive operation.
The solution wont be using a trigger pal.